# Missed Friday work because I mistakenly thought Labor Day was September 1st, how to explain?

Tags: united-states, colleagues, holidays

I worked abroad for half my career and always worked Labor Day weekend in the States as a contractor.

I totally was unaware it was not September 1st and blew off Friday. My job recently claimed my work was excellent but claim my lack of team communication needed to be fixed. Two days later I blow off Friday without telling anyone.

*How do I effectively explain being unaware of Labor Day to my co-worker without giving a bad impression or sounding ignorant?* Especially since my coworkers are foreign and I was born/raised here.

Comment: I find it hard to understand your post. I thought when you said you were working abroad, you meant you were working in the USA, and you are now back in your home country. For most countries, Labour Day would be May 1, which was 4 months ago, and not something you could be "confused" about. Even if you somehow confused it with USA's Labour Day, that's on the 1st Monday of September, not Friday, so I am confused what *your* confusion was. If the Labour Day in your home country is 1 September or some other date, please clarify that in the post. Mentioning the country name is also useful.

Comment: I was born and raised in USA, but worked in Asia for a number of years.

Comment: I think it is ironic you missed labour day by not being at work

Comment: Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". Anyone who was born and raised in US would know that Labor day is always on Monday.

Comment: Anyone who's worked abroad knows that some countries will not move the Bank holiday, E.g. France. This could be an easy mistake to make if you've been out of the US for some time

Comment: "How do I explain being unaware of Labor Day to my co-worker without sounding like an idiot." - I think that's pretty much unavoidable.

Comment: I still don't understand. If OP was unaware of Labor Day why didn't he go to work?

Comment: @TheMathemagician The OP was aware of Labor Day but had the date wrong. Labor Day is always the first Monday of September, but OP thought it was always September 1st.

Comment: @Draken, anyone schooled in the US should be well aware of Labor Day's schedule.  Not just because of classroom discussion, but also for the impact it has on the school calendar every year,

Comment: @cdkMoose When you have mutiple different systems, it's easy to get confused. I've worked in the UK, where bank holidays are moved to the closest Monday, and Luxembourg, where the bank holidays are fixed to the date and you get time in lieu if it's a weekend. That's why I always use a calendar to confirm my bank holidays. When you've worked different systems, it's very easy to get confused how bank holidays work. You can't assume that everyone has it correctly ingrained into their brain.

Comment: @Draken, I understand having multiple systems being confusing. But something that has impacted your life every year from 5 years old to 18 (22 if university) should have been learned at some point.  In the US, the start of each school year is a meaningful day in a child's life.  While different school districts in different areas will have  different schedules, the patterns around Labor day will be consistent and meaningful.

Comment: @cdkMoose Never left the keys at home when you left the house then? That's somethign that you have to do on a daily basis, but people make mistakes. They think they have them, they think they've done everything correctly and then oops! People make mistakes

Comment: @Draken , maybe I misread, but to me the post was about lack of knowledge "I was totally unaware", not accidental forgetfulness. I have forgotten my keys many times. Don't recall ever not knowing if today was a holiday from work

Comment: @cdkMoose  I assumed the monday holiday rule only applied when holidays fell on weekends or wasn't Friday. I also never started school after labor day. It's always been late august or early September if I recall. Usually I recall getting all four days off(Monday and Friday).

Comment: @deek,  I would have thought that by later years of school you would have seen that the holiday was always Monday even if you got the long weekend with Friday included.  It's not actually a Monday holiday rule, it's the Labor day rule.  Thanskgiving is always Thursday, even though you also got Friday off from school.

Comment: In @deek's defense, some teenagers go through school completely oblivious to things like this. Both my husband and my brother are these types of people who just don't pay attention and wouldn't have even noticed. This discussion on how legitimate their misunderstanding was is not really necessary. "I'm sorry, I've always worked on Labor day and didn't know it was the first Monday, not the first of the month" should suffice. People may raise their eyebrows but it's not that damning a mistake to make.

Comment: I find hard to believe they didn't even try to contact you. If I did what you did, I'd receive at least 5 calls and 2 emails from my manager before the morning was over.

Comment: @BgrWorker I got 1 email which I missed due to my phone being dead.

Answer (score 42):

> How do I explain being unaware of labor day to my co-worker with out
>   sounding like an idiot.

The truth is pretty much always the best explanation.

Sometimes it won't prevent folks from forming an impression of you that you would rather avoid. But that impression can fade with time as long as you avoid similar gaffes.

Usually self-deprecation told with a laugh is very easily forgiven.

Comment: yes, no other options really

Comment: If you're looking for phrasing examples, something like "In hindsight it seems silly, but I was somehow convinced that labor day is always on the first of September. I guess I learned this one the hard way!"

Answer (score 3):

You screwed up.  You know that, so that's a good first step.  I agree with Joe S on the first thing to do: tell them honestly what you did.

But to go forward, you need more than that, since this wasn't the first kind of problem related to your communications (and this certainly is, as your question suggests).  You need to *show* that you are going to fix this.

What kinds of things do you do to *proactively* prevent this from being a problem, in the future?  Come October 12, let's say you accidentally think it's Thanksgiving (perhaps you're Canadian) and don't come in to work.  What can you do, *now*, to make that less likely to happen, and less of an issue?  Here are some suggestions, but you should do whatever fits best in your corporate culture.

- Tell your coworkers how to contact you, outside of work.  Cell phone, text, whatever.  Hopefully they already know this, but make *sure*.
- Use the calendar feature in Outlook (or whatever you all use internally), and use it for *everything*.  Put all of your time off in there, even if it's just an hour or two.  And even if it's a holiday.  Then share that with the office.
- Send out "time off" emails.  Email the folks that you would expect to communicate daily with (or weekly, if you mostly work alone) a few days before *every* time off, to let them know how to contact you or who else to contact during your time off.
- If you have status meetings, mention time off including holidays during each one, up to the next one.

Whatever mitigation options you can come up with - *mention those* in the email.  (And *do* some of them *first*, before you send the email, so it's not just "promises" but real action.)  Send the email to everyone that was affected by it, not just your manager.

Here's an example.

> Hi folks,
>
> I was out Friday due to a confusion as to what day Labor Day was. I'm very sorry that I got that wrong, and didn't double check which day it was. I hope that it didn't cause too much difficulty for anyone, and I'll do my best to fix any problems that came about as a result so that my absence won't cause any significant delays or issues.
>
> I have updated my outlook calendar with all time off, including holidays, based on the corporate calendar available [here].  I will keep this up to date in the future, so that this kind of mistake doesn't happen again, and to make it easier for you all to know where I am.
>
> If ever I am not in the office and you need to get ahold of me for any reason, you can call or text my cell at (555)555-5555, or contact my manager, Jane Black.
>
> Again, my apologies for the mistake. I will do better in the future.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Deek

Answer (score 2):

> How do I effectively explain being unaware of Labor Day to my co-worker without giving a bad impression or sounding ignorant?

Not sure you can, you went AWOL without a valid reason which many would see as a fireable issue.

If communications weren't an issue you would know something of what they were doing on the holiday, and them of what you are doing, so the misunderstanding would have been apparent before it happened.  This will just highlight the issue even further and may lead to further repercussions.

Comment: Not knowing anything about the people or the culture at OP's work, I thought this answer was a little harsh or overbearing, but the last paragraph is actually tremendously important and accurate. The worst thing to ever do is confirm a negative impression and, well, even with an honest mistake, that's often what ends up happening.

Comment: I wouldn't want to work for any employer who would fire someone just because they didn't turn up one day, without hearing why.

Comment: No, as bad as an AWOL is, the OP has said the employer has raised communication issues, and what is this?  It's a pattern which may be acted on.  If someone on my team went AWOL I'd give them a chance to explain, but I would have also attempted to reach them when they didn't appear.  The fact they didn't says volumes about their feelings unfortunately.

Comment: Even in retail we didn't fire people for one no-call-no-show; it took two or three, depending on the frequency.  But the last paragraph, for sure.

Comment: @Simon B No call No Show is about the worst thing you can do at most jobs.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager it helped most of the office took the day off and I was well ahead of schedule in terms of dev tasks completed.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I effectively explain being unaware of Labor Day to my
>   co-worker without giving a bad impression or sounding ignorant?

You can not.  There were plenty of controls available to make sure you knew what days were holidays, and what days were expected work days.  While it may be understandable what happened here, it is not excusable.

So the best strategy is to avoid even trying to make excuses or try to explain why beyond saying you thought it was a holiday.  What is most important now is: what are you going to do to make sure nothing even remotely similar happens again?  You need to come up with a plan to convince your employer that you are serious about making sure that you improve.  That plan needs to demonstrate that.